# Access MP3 files on server from iOS.

Tags: ios, mysql, apache, file, server

I'm building a streaming app similar to pandora. However right now I'm storing all my files on http and accessing them with urls. Is there an alernative to this because all the files are in the public html folder? For example how does apps like pandora or spotify pull files off their servers. I'm new to web severs and not sure where to ask this question. I have a centos server on vps hosting with apache, MySQL, http, ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide the content as a bit stream rather than a file download.  The source of that data to send as a stream can be stored as binary data in a BLOB column in a database or as a regular file on a non-public part of the file system.  It really does not mater which one you use.

Storing them in the database gives your app a bit easier access and makes the app more portable since it is not restricted the file system level permissions.

The fact you currently have the files in a public folder is not really that critical of an issue since you are making them available for download.   You would just need to make sure you have an authentication requirement if you want to restrict who can access them.

Comment: Is there anything in the api so I can authorize the app access at run time so I don't have to keep authorizing access to password protected directories. I am just using avplayeritems with avqueueplayer. I seen using url requests but my avplayers use nsurl and I don't know how to switch them.

Comment: Also is there a way to access non public files from my iOS app?

Comment: What is "the API" you are asking about?  

Your server side app does not need to authorize anything to access files.  It needs needs permissions to access the files in question on the file system.

Comment: This answer just addressed being able to access non-public files.

Comment: Wait are you talking about trying to do all this from just the iOS app?  That does not work.  You will have to create a server side app to provide content from the sever if you want to do more than just access a pubic folder via HTTP.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted to know. What kind of protocol the server should use or something. I am just looking for clues where I can start from as I have no experience with web servers.

Comment: The protocol is determined by what your server side service(s) are using.  Most remote services generally use HTTP, but it could be FTP, or something else.